# Obter definição em DPI de imagem extraída de PDF

Tags: c#, imagem, pdf, itextsharp

Estou usando o **itextSharp** para extrair imagens de arquivos PDF.

Usei como base esse código: https://psycodedeveloper.wordpress.com/2013/01/10/how-to-extract-images-from-pdf-files-using-c-and-itextsharp/

Aqui está minha versão modificada para suportar arquivos em memória ao invés de ter que trabalhar com arquivos em disco:

```
    /// <summary>Helper class to extract images from a PDF file. Works with the most
    /// common image types embedded in PDF files, as far as I can tell.</summary>
    /// <example>
    /// Usage example:
    /// <code>
    /// foreach (var filename in Directory.GetFiles(searchPath, "*.pdf", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
    /// {
    ///    var images = ImageExtractor.ExtractImages(filename);
    ///    var directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename);
    ///
    ///    foreach (var image in images)
    ///    {
    ///       image.Save(Path.Combine(directory, name));
    ///    }
    ///  }
    /// </code></example>
    public static class PdfImageExtractor
    {
        #region Methods
        #region Public Methods

        /// <summary>Checks whether a specified page of a PDF file contains images.</summary>
        /// <returns>True if the page contains at least one image; false otherwise.</returns>
        public static bool PageContainsImages(byte[] pdfFile, int pageNumber)
        {
            using (var reader = new PdfReader(pdfFile))
            {
                var parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
                ImageRenderListener listener = null;
                parser.ProcessContent(pageNumber, (listener = new ImageRenderListener()));
                return listener.Images.Count > 0;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>Extracts all images (of types that iTextSharp knows how to decode) from a PDF file.</summary>
        public static List<System.Drawing.Image> ExtractImages(byte[] pdfFile)
        {
            var images = new List<System.Drawing.Image>();

            using (var reader = new PdfReader(pdfFile))
            {
                var parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
                ImageRenderListener listener = null;
                for (var i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
                {
                    parser.ProcessContent(i, (listener = new ImageRenderListener()));
                    var index = 1;
                    if (listener.Images.Count > 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Found {0} images on page {1}.", listener.Images.Count, i);
                        foreach (var pair in listener.Images)
                        {
                            images.Add(pair);
                            index++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return images;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>Extracts all images (of types that iTextSharp knows how to decode)
        /// from a specified page of a PDF file.</summary>
        /// <returns>Returns a generic <see cref="List&lt;System.Drawing.Image&gt;"/>,
        /// where the key is a suggested file name, in the format: PDF filename without extension,
        /// page number and image index in the page.</returns>
        public static List<System.Drawing.Image> ExtractImages(byte[] pdfFile, int pageNumber)
        {
            var images = new List<System.Drawing.Image>();
            using (var reader = new PdfReader(pdfFile))
            {
                var parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
                ImageRenderListener listener = null;

                parser.ProcessContent(pageNumber, (listener = new ImageRenderListener()));
                int index = 1;
                if (listener.Images.Count > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Found {0} images on page {1}.", listener.Images.Count, pageNumber);
                    foreach (System.Drawing.Image image in listener.Images)
                    {
                        images.Add(image);
                        index++;
                    }
                }

            }


            return images;
        }
        #endregion Public Methods
        #endregion Methods
    }
    internal class ImageRenderListener : IRenderListener
    {
        #region Fields
        List<System.Drawing.Image> images = new List<System.Drawing.Image>();
        #endregion Fields

        #region Properties
        public List<System.Drawing.Image> Images
        {
            get { return images; }
        }
        #endregion Properties

        #region Methods

        #region Public Methods
        public void BeginTextBlock() { }
        public void EndTextBlock() { }
        public void RenderImage(ImageRenderInfo renderInfo)
        {
            PdfImageObject image = renderInfo.GetImage();

            var imageBytes = image.GetImageAsBytes();
            var bytesType = image.GetImageBytesType();

            var fileExtension = bytesType.FileExtension;

            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
            {
                var drawingImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(memoryStream);

                var dpiX = drawingImage.HorizontalResolution;

                this.Images.Add(drawingImage);
            }
        }
        public void RenderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo) { }
        #endregion Public Methods
        #endregion Methods
    }
```

O problema é que no método `RenderImage` o valor da variável `dpiX` sempre é `96`. Eu gostaria de obter a **resolução original da imagem em DPI**, existe alguma maneira de fazer isso?

Para usar o método basta:

```
var pageImages = PdfImageExtractor.ExtractImages(fileBytes, pageNumber);
```

Para cada imagem, tentei converter para Bitmap também, mas obtive o mesmo resultado:

```
var bitmapImage = new Bitmap(pageImage);
var dpiX = bitmapImage.HorizontalResolution;
var dpiY = bitmapImage.VerticalResolution;
```

> Não quero definir por conta própria uma resolução, eu gostaria de
>   obter a resolução original da imagem.

Comment: A resolução original da imagem perdeu-se quando foi aplicada no pdf. A resolução é um valor arbitrário com o objetivo de passar pixels para centímetros (ou outra dimensão) e não fica guardado no pdf. O dpi no pdf poder ser qualquer coisa dependendo da escala aquando da aplicação da imagem.

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário. Existe alguma fonte para a afirmação de que "a resolução original da imagem perdeu-se quando foi aplicada no pdf"? A resolução pode ser recalculada de alguma forma nesse caso?

Comment: Se o objecto `PdfImageObject` não tem essa informação então não a conseguirá obter.

Comment: O objeto `PdfImageObject` de fato não possui nenhuma propriedade direta que disponibilize essa informação, mas imaginei que poderia haver alguma outra forma indireta de conseguir, entretanto até o momento não encontrei nada do tipo em minhas pesquisas, por isso vim atrás de ajuda.
Se o comentário do @PauloSoares tiver alguma fonte na qual eu possa me basear, então acredito que o assunto esteja parcialmente encerrado. Minha busca será apenas pela possibilidade de calcular isso de alguma forma.

Comment: Depende do PDF em si. O PDF pode ter passado por compressores que compactam a resolução para menor, neste caso, o PDF original sempre seria necessário; e não há como distinguir se o PDF é "comprimido" ou não.

Comment: **A resolução pode ser recalculada** quando o PDF é gerado. Isso depende de como e onde foi gerado o PDF.